# About Mac os 64-bit and 32-bit

Tags: macos

I have Problem in 64-bit and 32-bit in mac. i am using mac10.6 version.it support 64-bit default. when i run my project in terminal using makefile ,how to run 32bit and 64 bit api's separately? why some Framework api available only in 32-bit(lower version)? please clear my doubt

Comment: apparently someone doesn't like mac OS :\

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using gcc version 4.0 or later, and add -arch flags for the architectures you want (e.g. `-arch i386 or -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64` will compile for 32- and 63-bit Intel, and 32- and 64-bit PowerPC).  Apple's [64-bit transition guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/intro/intro.html) has a [relevant section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/building/building.html) with details.

As for APIs: Apple has started to deprecate some APIs (mainly Carbon), and has not updated them to support 64-bit mode.  Use Cocoa APIs instead.  Again, Apple's 64-bit transition guide has a [relevant section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/HighLevelAPIs/HighLevelAPIs.html) here, as well as a more detailed [Carbon 64-bit guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).